# Layer Style - save location in mssql-server

Tags: qgis, sql-server

Where is the save location of a QGIS-layer-style in a mssql-server?

I am user in a larger mssql-server-database with read and write permissions in a specific schema. On saving the style for a layer in the mssql-database, I get this message:

"Unable to save layer style. It's not possible to create the destination table on the database. Maybe this is due to table permissions. Please contact your database admin"

Will the destination table for the layer style be saved in my user-schema or in a different place (e.g. dbo)?

Comment: You might find it in the error logs. Check the Speech bubble icon in the bottom right of QGIS. It should have a "MSSQL" tab.

Comment: There is no MSSQL-tab!

Comment: Try getting the error and checking again? Also is there anything in the general tab? Also possibly do you have a server manager in MSSQL that shows running/attempted queries?

Comment: Sorry, but there is no error-info in the "Log Messages Panel". The manager of the mssql-sever asked me, where QGIS wants to save the layer-style-table.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the source code, it should just be:

```
[dbo].[layer_styles]
```

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=layer_styles&type=

With the full query as:

```
    bool execOk = query.exec( QString( "CREATE TABLE [dbo].[layer_styles]("
                                   "[id] int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,"
                                   "[f_table_catalog] [varchar](1024) NULL,"
                                   "[f_table_schema] [varchar](1024) NULL,"
                                   "[f_table_name] [varchar](1024) NULL,"
                                   "[f_geometry_column] [varchar](1024) NULL,"
                                   "[styleName] [varchar](1024) NULL,"
                                   "[styleQML] [text] NULL,"
                                   "[styleSLD] [text] NULL,"
                                   "[useAsDefault] [int] NULL,"
                                   "[description] [text] NULL,"
                                   "[owner] [varchar](1024) NULL,"
                                   "[ui] [text] NULL,"
                                   "[update_time] [datetime] NULL"
                                   ") ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]" ) );
```